# Who would be responsive for damage caused after cloning foreign application but NOT running it as freelancer?

Tags: freelancing, legal

This is just theoretical question, without context.

In case

- somebody hire me (as freelancer (I'm A1))
- client (A2) wants to develop **CLONE** of an existing application from B1 company
- after some time I give completed application to my client (A2)
- after some time original owners of application (B1) I cloned want to go to court

Who would be responsive for damage caused to B1 company?

Me as freelancer (A1)  or my client (A2) which runs that site and take money from it?

Comment: If you are worried about this situation how about just telling them.  Any work will be total rework.  This means if it took you 40 hours before it will still take you 40 hours to redevelop it.  I am shocked your even getting work like this at your age.

Comment: @Ramhound: Read first sentence, please

Comment: In this theoretical context you need a lawyer. There are too many things to consider.

Comment: @oleksii: but by copying everything and giving my work to someone DOES NOT mean that I caused damaged to B1. It's on customer, how would he use it. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @genesis, there are just too many things to consider. Speaking abstractly, given you copy Windows and sell it to Apple via Oracle, do you think you will stay white and fluffy? If you are worried about some actions against you, talk to a lawyer, you may get some free advice in other organisations. Do not leave the mess on its own.

Comment: Depends on the state with its laws, where it happens.

Comment: Don't take jobs like this that cross ethical lines.  Problem solved!

Comment: Scott: I did not say I will! It's just theoretical  question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: everyone involved. That's how lawyers work

Long answer: this depends on what exactly 'clone' means. If your work does not violate actual patents (for example being a clean-room reimplementation) there's hardly anything B1 can do. This does not mean however they will not try.

As with all things legal, this is also dependent on where you and your employee are located, details of your contract etc. In other words - consult a lawyer not an internet site.

Standard discalimer: I am not a lawyer

Comment: Thanks for answer. I cannot hire lawyer, look at my age. 'Clone' means to take CSS, images, html & rewrite PHP for example, to make Facebook clone look like http://faithout.com/ (clone of facebook with changed colors)

Comment: Oh great! You're not of legal age, so A2 can't hire you. Problem solved ;P
Seriously though: people are doing social websites in dozens, and I don't see Facebook suing them (why would it anyway - they were not the first social site). Images, CSS and other content however is protected by copyright, so usual consequences for violating it apply.

Comment: Actually brigarde is allowed from 15 in Czech Republic. It's not allowed to take brigade in 15 years in another statE?

Comment: Facebook sued [Teachbook](http://teachbook.com/) [\[source\]](http://money.cnn.com/2010/08/26/technology/teachbook/index.htm)

Comment: @genesis: 16 just behind your North-Eastern border. And 'teachbook' case seems to be based on trademark violation more than functionality cloning

Comment: In this case facebook would have to sue every libraries with "book" in domain name...

Comment: Not libraries, but social sites, with name ending in 'book'. That was their rationale for this case.

Comment: But Facebook sued site which contains "Book of teachers" - it's nothing to do with "Book of faces"

Comment: Now you're getting into legal dispute, and I am not going into that :P

Comment: Are you suprised? I will maybe go to lawyer high school & university :p

Comment: @genesis - Actually in this case you could not afford to not have an attorney.  You are talking about knowingly stealing an appilcation.  Even if they have difficulty proving it in this case it looks like a text book case of infringement and theft, and possibly software piracy.  You would need someone skilled and knowledgable in these matters to help you through this and minimize your exposure.  As for defending yourself there is a saying that goes something like "A man who acts as his own attorney has a fool for a client."